# How to configure an attribute to be edited with a RichTextBox editor in SmartEdit?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I noticed that **CMSParagraphComponent**'s **content** attribute can be edited using a RichTextBox like depicted in below image:
[image]

I want to edit my custom attribute in the same way(with the depicted RichTextBox). How can I do that ?

I tried configuring the ***backoffice-config.xml*** to use the wysiwyg:

```
<context merge-by="type" type="MyType" component="editor-area" module="moduleBackoffice">
    <editorArea:editorArea xmlns:editorArea="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/component/editorArea">
        <editorArea:tab merge-mode="replace" name="hmc.properties">
            <editorArea:section  name="hmc.properties">
                <editorArea:attribute
                        editor="com.hybris.cockpitng.editor.localized(com.hybris.cockpitng.editor.wysiwyg)"
                        qualifier="customStringAttribute"/>
            </editorArea:section>
        </editorArea:tab>
    </editorArea:editorArea>
</context>
```

But this only reflects in backoffice and has no effect on SmartEdit.

How can I use the RichTextBox in smartEdit ?

Hybris version: **6.7.0.3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be resolved by creating below Spring bean:

```
<bean class="de.hybris.platform.cmsfacades.types.service.impl.DefaultComponentTypeAttributeStructure" p:typecode="MyType" p:qualifier="customStringAttribute">
    <property name="populators">
        <set>
            <ref bean="richTextComponentTypeAttributePopulator" />
            <ref bean="requiredComponentTypeAttributePopulator" />
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I added above defined bean in my **${extensionname}**-spring.xml, restarted the server and everything worked as expected. The **MyType**'s **customStringAttribute** is now configurable from smartedit in the exact same way as **CMSParagraphComponent**'s **content** is.